# Cannot able to submit the form automatically

Tags: php, javascript

I have written this code. Here after logging into facebook, the document needs to redirect to check3.php. Here is the code..

```
  <html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">  
        <h1><a href="index.php">ReviewBox</a></h  
        <ul id="nav"> 
        <li><a href="#">Real Reviews For Real People</a></li>
        <li style="background: url(images/request.png);display:block; margin : 0 10px 0 0;float:right;text-indent: -9999px; width : 200px; height: 30px;"><a href="request.php">Request Review From Friends</a></li><br/>

        </ul><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
        <div id="container">
           <div id="content">

           <p>Someone is always out there, waiting to know what you have to say.
           So why not speak out with ReviewBox?</p><br/>

        <h6>Get Started!</h6><br/><br/>
        <center>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script language="javascript" src="json2.js"> </script>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script>
          FB.init({ 
            appId:'xxxxxxxxxxxx', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true
          });
        </script>
       <fb:login-button perms="read_stream,publish_stream,email,offline_access">
        Login with Facebook
        </fb:login-button>

        <br/><br/>
        <p>Like ReviewBox :</p><br/><center>
        <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxxxxxx" send="false" width="220" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like></center>

         <script> 
          FB.api('/me',function(response) {

         setCookie("fbname",response.name,365);
         setCookie("fbid",response.id,365);
         setCookie("checker",1,1);
         var username=getCookie("fbid");

        if (username!="undefined" && username!="")
         {
           alert("Welcome Again, " + response.name + "!");
           sample();
           //window.location.reload();  
         }
         else 
         {
           alert("Welcome Guest! Please Login with Facebook To Get Started With ReviewBox!");
           username=response.id;
           username2=response.name;
           if (username!=null && username!="")
           {
            setCookie("fbid",username,365);
            setCookie("fbname",username2,365);
            setCookie("checker",1,1);
           }
        }
     });


    function sample()
    {
    document.form1.submit();
    }
    </script>

    <form name="form1" action="check3.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="fb_user" id="fb_user" value="" />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But when I run this code and after logging into facebook the code inside sample() function is not executed.. as a result my page does not redirects to check3.php.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Learn,

First of all, determine whether or not the Facebook reponse object actually contains a value.  It is possible that the API is for some reason, not returning an ID result?

Once you verify that the API is indeed returning a value, perhaps use that in your "if" statement, instead of username?

I don't know exactly what is wrong, but I am fairly certain that the "fbid" value is not being set inside the cookie, which to me implies that the API is not returning a correct result, or you are passing in invalid parameters to the API.

Good luck!

H

Comment: the api is returning the ids and it is working. i have checked that. if i put some other code in sample function like printing something it is working. but when i put document.form1.submit() in sample func it is not working???

Comment: @learn, a Ha! I just looked up documentation on accessing Form elements with JavaScript and I found this article: [JS Form Access](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-all-form-objects.phtml).  Forms are available inside the DOM like this: `document.forms[1]` .  If instead you want to use the form id, then get a reference to it like this: `var myForm = document.getElementById('form1');` then use "myForm" to access your form values or methods.  Also you may want to investigate [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a js library, that can easily do things like form submission.

Comment: @learn try looking into jQuery, it would make things even easier